# JavaScript Observable Property

Tags: javascript

In trying to learn more about JavaScript patterns I created the following 2 "Meters" based on an example I found.  Is Meter1 better because it uses the Observable Property (or so I think) pattern?  Would this pattern be used real-world or not really because of all the frameworks available?

```
//Meter1 - Observable Property Pattern
var Meter1 = function (count) {
    var countChanging = [],
        countChanged = [];

    this.count = function (val) {
        if (val !== undefined && val !== count) {
            for (var i = 0; i < countChanging.length; i++) {
                if (!countChanging[i](this, val)) {
                    return count;
                }
            }
            count = val;
            for (var i = 0; i < countChanged.length; i++) {
                countChanged[i](this);
            }
        }
        return count;
    };

    this.increment = function () {
        return count = count + 1;
    }

    this.onCountChanging = function (callback) {
        countChanging.push(callback);
    };

    this.onCountChanged = function (callback) {
        countChanged.push(callback);
    };
};

var meter = new Meter1(5);
var btnClick = document.getElementById('btnClick');

btnClick.addEventListener('click', function () {    
    meter.count(meter.count() + 1);
}, false);

meter.onCountChanging(function (b, count) {
    if (count > 10) {
        document.getElementById('numClicks').innerHTML = "Enough already!!!!!";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

meter.onCountChanged(function () {
    document.getElementById('numClicks').innerHTML = "Test " + meter.count();
});


//Meter2 - Does the same thing, is Observable Property pattern better?
var Meter2 = function (count) {
    this.count = 0;
};

var meter2 = new Meter2(5);
var btnClick2 = document.getElementById('btnClick2');

btnClick2.addEventListener('click', function () {    
    meter2.count = meter2.count + 1;
    if (meter2.count > 10) {
        document.getElementById('numClicks2').innerHTML = "Enough already!!!!!";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('numClicks2').innerHTML = "Test " + meter2.count;
    }
}, false);


<body>

<div id="numClicks">Test</div>
<div id="numClicks2">Test</div>

<button id="btnClick">Click - Meter</button>
<button id="btnClick2">Click - Meter 2</button>

</body>
</html>
<script src="../js/generalTesting.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is meant by "Observable" here? (i don't see any observation, ex Object.observe() or Object.watch()...)

Comment: When count changes by clicking the button the html is updated, so I was thinking it was "Observable", but I may be looking at it incorrectly.

Comment: You should definitely rely on a framework that takes care of all that plumbing.

Comment: fwiw, i like the 2nd way better, it's more readable, and even after several mins of staring, i'm not sure what the point of all the code in #1 is, especially pushing around all those arrays... KISS. if some framework made #1 as short as #2, and it had other benefits, then it might be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I thought the pattern was interesting but didn't know how I would use it or what the benefit would be.